# How do I read Text property of silverlight toolkit NumericUpDown control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, toolkit, numericupdown

I want to read value entered in the NumericUpDown control. How do i read it?

XAML Layout is follows

```
  <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelStyle_LableValue}">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=ViewItem.Addition, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}" />
                            <inputToolkit:NumericUpDown Style="{StaticResource NumericUpdownStyle_Addition}"
                                                        Value="{Binding Items.RightSpecGlass.Addition, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                        TabIndex="8" />
                        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Have you set your view's datacontext ?

Comment: @S.Amani yes i have set. I want to read the value in code behind of XAML

Comment: So you want to get its value with binding, yes ?

Comment: Have you initiate those stuffs ? I mean Items and RightSpecGlass ?

Comment: @S.Amani everything is working fine. I got bug in my system. That is UpDownControl us designed for Dutch culture so it accept 1,2 as number but when user enters 1.2 it show 12 in updown control where i want 1.2 internally converted to 1,2. please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039529/how-to-get-string-value-entered-in-numericupdown-silverlight-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
numericUpDown.Value; // To get decimal value of control
```

or

```
numericUpDown.Text; // To get value as string of control
```

Comment: He wants to bind NumericUpDown's value not to get its value directly by naming the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Since you have bind your view context, I think there is no reason to avoid get NumericUpDown's value except :

1- Maybe you forgot to initialize those classes or properties `Items` and/or `RightSpecGlass`

2- Your class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to raise when any control's value change in view. `Addition` property has to raise property change event in its setter.

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private int _addition;
    public Int32 Addition
    {
        get { return _addition; }
        set
        {
            _addition= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Addition");
        }
    }
```

hope this help.

Comment: i have used View Model its working fine . I got a bug which I described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039529/how-to-get-string-value-entered-in-numericupdown-silverlight-control . Once i will get the string value entered in the numeric control i can parse it as i want.