# How to divide a string value by another string value, each containing a numeric value

Tags: c#

How do I make my label display `NumericUpDown1` / `NumericUpDown2` properly?

Here is what I have

```
label6.Text = Convert.ToString(NumericUpDown1.Value/NumericUpDown2.Value);
```

I have also tried

```
label6.text = NumericUpDown1.value/NumericUpDown2.value
```

and got an error saying

> Cannot Implicitly Convery blah blah into bytes

An after i start my project it crashes ( I have it so as soon as my project opens it tries to display `NumUD1` / `NumUD2` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most simple terms:

```
decimal d = (NumericUpDown1.value/NumericUpDown2.value);

stringVal = System.Convert.ToString(d);

label6.text = stringVal;
```

**Or** you could create a subclass of NumericUpDown and override the ParseValue method (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039529/how-to-get-string-value-entered-in-numericupdown-silverlight-control)):

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown {

  protected override double ParseValue(string text)
  {
     // Change text to whatever you want
     string newText = FixText(text);

     // Call base implementation.
     base.ParseValue(newText);
  }

  private static string FixText(string inputText) {
    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE.
  } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for having a misleading comment, what i meant was i would like for the label to show the results of NumericUpDown1 DIVIDED BY NumericUpDown2 :)

Comment: Updated my answer, I don't have an IDE so it's just from memory. I'm not a c# programmer...

Answer (score 1):

Convert the values to `int`, then perform division and then assign it to `label6.Text` by converting to `string`:

```
label6.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString())/Convert.ToInt32(NumericUpDown1.Value.ToString())).ToString();
```

Comment: @JacobReid: That was because I forgot to remove `()` after `Value`. Now I have updated my answer.